# Unable to add folder to git

Tags: git

I had the folder in another rep, that one had problems too, so I deleted it and copy it's content to another rep, but when I try to add it to the rep, I'm unable to

```
C:\Users\35192\Desktop\ReactNativeTutorials>git add *                                                                
error: 'tutorial_project/' does not have a commit checked out                                                           
fatal: adding files failed
```

However, the folder itself is untracked

```
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.                                                                                                                                                                                                 Untracked files:                                                                                                          
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)                                                                
tutorial_project/
```

I've checked a couple of stack answers but none have helped

Comment: Have you tried with 'git add .' ?

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use '`*`' with git add: '`*`' would be expanded by the shell, which is not needed here (`git add .` is enough)

Second, check if `tutorial_project/` has a `.git/` subfolder in it. If so, you would add a nested repository.
Delete it, and then the `git add .` step will work.